# Sharepoint restore

Tags: sharepoint

I have an issue with restoring a sharepoint backup (2007) to a local virtual host. the error message, points to a version number that I cannot identify: 1364415309.1262568012.1.1

I matched this with the version of MOSS2007 installed and there is no match. Can anyone tell me what this number represent as I'm completely clueless.

Thanks.

Eric

Comment: What does the error message say exactly?

Answer (score 0):

If you are restoring a SharePoint backup to a different server than you took it from, you might try checking the version of WSS, MOSS and SQL Server. Generally, you want to be restoring from and to the same versions, but you might be ok with newer versions. Older versions could cause problems.

Did you check the Sharepoint ULS Logs in the SharePoint Root? If the event log doesn't give you more detail, these texted based logs should.